# Truffle Dapp Communication

Tags: dapp-development, truffle

In truffle, a dapp is deployed using the port of running geth node (in testnet). Then how will another machine node will communicate to that dapp because it is impossible to run a node on same port with different machine?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you deploy an app with Truffle, you are actually deploying a contract and the font end is a simple html/css website which can interact with the contract instance.

Technically, you are not touching the actual ethereum node, it is running somewhere else and any other app can communicate with the geth instance with no issues.

Comment: Thanks, you mean we need to have similar dapp at both the end? And also tell me that the communicating nodes should be peers or not?

Comment: Please @niksmac respond soon

Comment: Another dapp can communicate to the same contract you deployed right?

Comment: it means @niksmac the communicating node will not have any own contract. It will be just communicating with the contract deployed by first node?

Comment: Yes, whenever you deploy it it lives in the blockchain, you can use the contract

Comment: tell me @niksmac, if a dapp is trying to communicate with another dapp then the associated geth nodes should be peers?

Comment: not necessarily, nodes are peers when they are connected in between, no relation to DApp.

Comment: which function we need to use in truffle to use the contract on blockchain, because contract deployed by truffle is not accessible by geth node. I am trying using contractname.at(contractaddress), but it's not working @niksmac

Comment: Please @niksmac reply soon, i am new to this technology, help me. We can connect on skype if you are comfortable with it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/39669/discussion-between-aniket-and-niksmac).