# Dapp Communication using smart contract written in solidity in truffle framework

Tags: go-ethereum, dapp-development, truffle

How will two Dapps, developed using truffle framework, will communicate with the contract deployed by one Dapp ( Consider testnet using **geth**)?

Comment: Related http://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/3662/truffle-dapp-communication

Answer (score 2):

When you deploy a contract, it gets assigned an Ethereum Contract Address. If you want to interact with a contract you must load the contract address to your wallet. (Take a look at how it is done with DAO: https://daohub.org/voting.html)

To interact with a Contract you need 2 things:

- The contract's Address
- The contract's JSON interface

By using these two you are able to load and invoke a contract onto web3.js and begin to interact with it.

> navigate to 'Contracts'. Select then 'Watch Contract'. In the "Watch Contracts" interface, type 'The DAO' as the Contract name, paste the contract address, and the JSON interface. Click 'OK'.
>
> With the contract interface registered, click "The DAO" in your custom contract section, and wait a few seconds. You are now able to use the interface and interact with the contract.